# Discard all core data changes from a certain point

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm developing a dating app and I want to create an options screen in witch the user goes and change his information. All information is stored in the core data. All changes will apply only when the user press save, or else the app will discard them.

I tried it whith parallel objects but I'm wondering if there is a mechanism in core data for this. Like multiple managedObjectContexts

Comment: you can use concurrency features in Coredata.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly that. [You can have a heirarchy of contexts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001182-256616) and propagate changes up the chain or choose not to.

The easiest way is to create a child context for the screen and discard all changes if not saved. Thus, when discarded, there are no dirty objects in your main context that could be unintendedly saved.