# Core Data ChildContext Updating

Tags: core-data

I am working on a Core Data application and want to use child context to update an expense entity. I am passing the expense entity along with the childContext to the EditExpenseScreen as shown below:

```
BudgetDetailScreen.swift

     EditExpenseScreen(expense: expenseConfig.expense)
                        .environment(\.managedObjectContext, expenseConfig.childContext)
```

The editExpenseConfig is initialized using the long press gesture as shown below:

```
 ExpenseCellView(expense: expense)
                            .onLongPressGesture {
                                editExpenseConfig = EditExpenseConfig(expense: expense, context: context)
                            }
```

In the EditExpenseScreen I directly bind the expense entity to the textfields as shown below.

```
struct EditExpenseScreen: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var expense: Expense
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var context
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    
    private var titleBinding: Binding<String> {
        Binding {
            expense.title ?? ""
        } set: { newValue in
            expense.title = newValue
        }
    }
    
    private var tagsBinding: Binding<Set<Tag>> {
           Binding(
               get: { Set(expense.tags?.compactMap { $0 as? Tag } ?? []) },
               set: { newValue in expense.tags = NSSet(array: Array(newValue)) }
           )
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("Title", text: titleBinding)
            TextField("Amount", value: $expense.amount, format: .number)
                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
            TextField("Quantity", value: $expense.quantity, format: .number)
            TagsView(selectedTags: tagsBinding)
        }
}
```

When the user edits the TextFields it automatically updates the expense object. If I close the modal without saving it still shows the updates in the expense model since it was passed as a reference. What can I do in this scenario? Should I not directly binding the expense object to the textfields.

Comment: Does this answer help you somhow: [stackoverflow.com/questions/35130518](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35130518/discard-all-core-data-changes-from-a-certain-point). I was using [`context.rollback()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506942-rollback) to discard changes made to the objects but I'm not sure if this would fit your needs.